# Monkey patching extra events in Node.js HTTP/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js

This question is related to [Express](http://expressjs.com) under [Node.js](http://nodejs.org).

## Background

With Express, you stack up several "middleware" modules to handle a specific HTTP request.

```
app.use(express.logger());
app.use(express.favicon()));
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session());
app.use(app.router);
```

When a request comes in, Express goes through all of the functions in the stack until a module handles the request.  Specifically, each middleware module is a `function (req, res, next)`, and that function will call `next()` to call the next module in the stack.  Functions can modify data in the `req` or `res` objects if they choose.

## The Problem

I was interested in making custom log middleware modules for my Express application, and I needed to use more than one module at a time.  The data I need to log cannot be logged until the response has been sent to the client.  (I am tracking bytes sent, and the amount of time a connection was established.)  Unfortunately, Node.js's HTTP response object [does not raise an `end` event](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse).  Presumably, this is because it is up to the application to do any "end" work prior to calling `.end()` on the response object in the first place.  Express does not expose a hook prior to `.end()` being called.

Express/Connect's built-in logger middleware is able to track how long a request was running, so I decided to see what method they use.  They actually [replace the `res.end` function](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/logger.js) with their own.  When their own `res.end` function is called, it swaps the old `res.end` back in place, finishes logging, then calls `res.end` with the parameters that their own `res.end` was called with.  Their method works, but can be problematic when a handful of modules try to do this.  (The order in which `res.end` function replacement occurs becomes critical.)

## My Solution

I have used their method to patch `res` to fire `end` events so that any module in the chain can subscribe to that event in the usual way.

```
function (req, res, next) {
    var end = res.end;

    res.end = function () {
        res.end = end;
        res.emit('end');
        res.end.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    next();
}
```

Then, all my logger module has to do is:

```
res.on('end', function () { /* log here */ });
```

Is there any problem with what I have done?  Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

I did the following for something similar.  This uses the closure to create a chain-of-command pattern.

```
function (req, res, next) {
  var realEnd = res.end;
  res.end = function () {
    var realEndArgs = arguments;
    req.log.info ("HTTP RESPONSE CODE " + res.statusCode);
    realEnd.apply (res, realEndArguments);
  }
  next();
}
```

You could instead of logging the status code, do res.emit('end') as you described, or anything else, before returning control to the original res.end (which may itself be a replacement).  Or, you could do directly in this function whatever you want to do in response to the end event.

Note: I explicitly store res.end's arguments in realEndArguments in case I later add anything asynchronous, because arguments would then refer to the asynchronous action's callback's arguments instead of res.end's arguments.  A subtle bug I ran into at first.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and published the package [express-end](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-end) to solve this limitation.
The code is quite similar to [Brad](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/12199/brad)'s solution with additional check.

```
var endMw = function(req, res, next) {

  if (!res._orig_end_handler) {

    res._orig_end_handler = res.end;

    res.end = function () {
      res.end = res._orig_end_handler;
      res.emit('end');
      res.end.apply(this, arguments);
    };

  } else {
    debug('Warning: res.end() function is already overridden');
  }

  next();

};
```

Hope, the package will save some time to somebody else.

Upd:
As this code is utility, to be used in the package and may be reused by other packages, I assume the check is needed to prevent double patching of `res.end()` if the middleware is applied twice. In order to do that, I store original handler in property of `res` object, not in the closure.

Comment: Please add some explanation to explain how your code is an improvement over the original solution.